# JSF 2.2 h:inputFile update page after a commanbutton is firea

Tags: ajax, file-upload, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I am new in developing web sites with JSF.

I need to build a page where the user can either use an inputText to add a value or an inputFile component to upload a file with values and an outputvalue forthe result of the action

the problem is, that when i have the enctype="multipart/form-data" and i press my commandbutton the outputvalue does notrefreshed wit he updated result. I must reload the page from the browser to check what happened.
If i remove enctype="multipart/form-data" from the form tag then i cant upload any file (the automated button is missing)

PS this is happening when i use f:ajax tag to render either the inputText or the inputFile
without the f:ajax tag it works well but i need to render one of these two componenets each time

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue. It's already reported as [issue 3048](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3048) by yours truly and fixed in 2.2.5 which has a planned release date of 2 january 2014 — due to the holidays. In the meanwhile, you can get away by grabbing the 2.2.5 snapshot. [Here's the API JAR](https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/snapshots/com/sun/faces/jsf-api/2.2.5-SNAPSHOT/) and [here's the impl JAR](https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/snapshots/com/sun/faces/jsf-impl/2.2.5-SNAPSHOT/).